# What is the meaning of the suffix T in T-SQL statements?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I seen some queries including table name with t suffix. like

```
select * 
from MyTable t
```

or

```
select Col1, Col2, Col3 
from MyTable t with (nolock) 
where ....
```

I searched, but I was not able to understand what is the purpose of including the t after inserting table name.

Comment: It's called an alias. The *real* question you should be asking yourself is, why are you using `NOLOCK` when you don't understand the implications and consequences of its use.

Comment: `NOLOCK` means `read dirty and duplicate data while taking excessive locks  and randomly throwing errors`. It doesn't mean `go fast`, it means the query has a serious performance problem that someone tried to cover up

Comment: `I searched` aliases are fundamental SQL concepts, used in all databases. They're mentioned in *all* articles, tutorials and courses for the simple reason that nobody wants to write the full table or column names all the time. In many cases they're necessary, eg when you want to join a table to itself, or when a query uses multiple tables with one or more identical names

Comment: @Larnu Thank you. is mean shorter way "as t"

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos calm down  is sample query. I not using always with(nolock)

Comment: Some people ise `AS` some don't, it's more preference. It's not really *that* much shorter. What is *way* short is `SELECT t1.Col1, T2.Col1` over `SELECT Table1.Col1, Table2.Col2`.

Comment: You should *never* use it. If you have to ask what a table alias is, I suspect this came from legacy code with performance issues. `NOLOCK` is essentially a tornado siren warning that the queries have performance or concurrency issues that were covered up. Quite often the coverup results in other, hard to diagnose errors. Beware, there are other dragons in that system

Answer (score 3):

So, It is alias. if you have just one select without join it does not give benefits.
if you have select like it:

```
select t1.Col1,t2.Col1,t1.Col3,t2.Col4
from MyTable t1
inner join MyTable2 t2 on t1.Col1 = t2.Col2
```

Then alias is a big comfort

Answer (score 3):

In that case this is an alias to the table name. So `select * from MyTable t` is equivalent to `select * from MyTable as t`. You can use any permitted literal instead of `t`. For example: `select tbl.Col1 from MyTable tbl`.